# Carregar imagens pela primeira vez num site

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel-4

Neste site [www.nomalism.com](http://www.nomalism.com) existe um problema: Ao abrir o site pela primeira vez, especialmente na loja (opção pesquisa ou search) nota-se que as imagens aparecem desfocadas ou desproporcionais. Fazemos F5 e depois já aparecem correctamente, por causa de serem carregadas via cache.

Se limparmos os temporários do browser, volta a acontecer o mesmo. O que poderá ser?

Site desenvolvido em laravel 4 e angular.js

Efeito "1ª vez"
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Efeito "2ª vez" após o refresh da página:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui temos internet Fibra 100Mb e consigo verificar em Firefox e Chrome, últimas versões em Windows 7.

Comment: Acessei o site e não percebi nada de incomum. Em que ponto exatamente está o problema? Estou usando Chrome ultima versao em Windows 7.

Comment: Aqui também não me pareceu estar com problema, estou usando Chrome Windows 8. http://imgur.com/j3nwmAH

Comment: Aqui também nenhuma anormalidade - FF 38.0.5 + WIN7 64

Comment: Tenho um colega, fora daqui, que me confirma o problema descrito, apenas em Firefox.

Comment: Sim, realmente está com o problema, minha internet é 60 megas, utilizo windows 10, porém é rápido demais e tem que visualizar bem....  ficarei no aguardo da resposta pois poderá ser útil no futuro.

Comment: Poderá ser "bug" no script de AngulaJS?

Comment: O que eu percebi é o seguinte. Suas imagens possuem tamanho superior ao que está sendo exibido e há uma discrepância entre a resolução que deveria estar como dots per pixel mas está em dots per inch.
Eu troquei aqui `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:2),only screen and (min-resolution:144dpi)` no seu arquivo chosen.css para `@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:1.5),only screen and (min-resolution:144dppx)` mas ainda não deu certo. Tem também um efeito transition com tempo de 150ms. Talvez esteja em um desses itens ou pode ser o entrelaçamento das imagens

Comment: Eu acredito que isso não seja um bug e sim o comportamento normal de exibição de imagens. Elas estão sendo carregadas e provavelmente seus jpegs estão como progressivos. Não há nada a fazer a menos que não queira isso de jeito nenhum  e nesse caso precisará usar um script de pre-load-images, mas vai ter o inconveniente de ter uma espera antes da imagem estar totalmente carregada.